# MySQL trigger is producing a syntax error, but I'm not sure what is wrong with it

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064, database-trigger

I've created a trigger to update one table once an item is inserted into another. The trigger will also check one of the values being inserted into the new table, and using an if/elseif, will perform the appropriate Update query. I'm running in to a syntax error, but I'm not sure what's wrong with my syntax

```
 CREATE TRIGGER Create_Media_Like_Trigger AFTER INSERT ON MediaLike
    FOR EACH ROW
            IF NEW.likeType = 'LIKE' THEN
                UPDATE Media 
                SET Media.numLikes = Media.numLikes + 1 
                WHERE Media.mediaId = NEW.mediaId
            ELSEIF NEW.likeType = 'DISLIKE' THEN
                UPDATE Media 
                SET Media.numLikes = Media.numLikes - 1 
                WHERE Media.mediaId = NEW.mediaId
            END IF;
```

I'm receiving an syntax error on or near the ELSEIF line, but I cant figure out what is wrong with it

Comment: You need a semicolon to terminate each `UPDATE` statement, or any other type of statement inside the IF/THEN/ELSE blocks. See examples in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html

Comment: You need put ; at ending of each statement

Comment: @BillKarwin I've also tried that, and it just creates more syntax errors

Comment: You need to use a `BEGIN`/`END` block if you use any compound statements in your trigger. You will also need to learn about `DELIMITER`. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Comment: @JoshMontgomery MySQL requires statement delimiters, for multi-statement triggers and procedures you must first override the current delimiter, typically with `DELIMITER $$`, so the delimiters within the trigger/procedure to not terminate its definition prematurely. It's covered pretty thoroughly in the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)